# Web user control member variable not accessible when not declared static

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, webusercontrol, member-variables

I am creating a web user control using C# to play some .wav files in the server. Following is my code.

```
public partial class WaveFilePlayer : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    //private string[] files;
    private static string[] files;

    protected void ButtonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string resourcePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourcePath"];
        string searchPattern = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchPattern"];

        files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);
    }

    protected void ButtonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = ListBoxFiles.SelectedIndex;

        SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(files[selectedIndex]);
        soundPlayer.Play();
    }
```

As seen in the code above I declare `string[] files` as a member variable. Then I assign it in the `ButtonLoad_Click` method. But it throws a `NullReferenceException` when I try to access it in the `ButtonPlay_Click` method unless `string[] files` is declared static.

Does it mean that a new object of `System.Web.UI.UserControl` is not created while loading the user control in a asp.net page? And does it mean that when multiple clients (browsers) try to play the .wav files, only one instance of the `string[] files` is created at the server to be used by all clients?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is impossible to access it"? What error are you getting?

Comment: @JonSkeet it throws a `NullReferenceException` when accessing `files` variable

Comment: Well, I suspect it's throwing a NullReferenceException when you *dereference* the value of the `files` variable. Just accessing it is fine, and will get you a `null` reference, for the reasons in my answer. Please be more specific in future questions - "impossible to access" sounds like a compile-time error...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, I'll try to be more specific in future to my best..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem isn't that it can't be *accessed*, at all. I strongly suspect that the problem is that you've got two different requests, and therefore two different instances of `WaveFilePlayer` - so when you're executing `ButtonPlay_Click`, the `files` variable will be null unless you've written some code to persist it between requests.

Options here would be view state or some server-side session. You should *not* use a static variable, as that will basically mean you've got a single variable shared between *all* requests (for all users).

Comment: @manas: The second paragraph of my answer gives the alternatives. Basically you've got to propagate the data somehow - either via the client or at the server. This is a fundamental part of writing web applications.

Comment: Sorry, but it is a bit difficult for me to understand the first part of the second paragraph

Comment: @manas: Which bit? View state? Did you try searching for "asp.net view state"? There's plenty of information on it. Likewise a search for "asp.net session" gives plenty of hits.